# Is there a way to loop a console command in Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora

**The Problem:**

I'm trying this (as root) in Fedora 19's console:

> yum install httpd

All it returns is this:

> loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekits Error: Cannot retrieve
>   metalink for repository: fedora/19/x86_64. Please verify its path and
>   try again.

Been having this error infrequently, but when I do get it, I get it for a day.

**What I tried:**

`yum update` returns the same error.

This has gone on for awhile, basically an offshoot of my previous question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/684260/error-can-not-retrieve-metalink-for-repository-fedora-19-x86-64)

If I wait long enough, the console command will eventually work. But is there a way to loop the command until it is successful?

Comment: you may distort `watch` use for this purpsoe, although it won't stop once it worked and continue until it receives a sigterm/Ctrl+C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
 while true; do
    yum install httpd && break
    sleep 10
 done
```

should work. (Sleep amount is in seconds).

You can type it in a single line adding `;` like this:

```
while true; do yum install httpd && break; sleep 10; done
```

**ADD**:

As Politowski suggests in comment, you can try also:

```
 while ! yum install httpd; do sleep 10; done
```

which may look nicer/shorter/clearer/easier to remember/understand to someone. (Thought there's at least one shell which can't run it, but it's not common on "Linux" systems, so almost surely you have not to worry about it).

Comment: Do I just type this as is in the console? What does the `sleep` do, and how does it detect if the command was successful? Just curious.

Comment: single line is nicer for console, but you can input it in the other way too, the shell will just ask for the next expected line. The sleep "sleeps" for N seconds. E.g. if you want to retry after a minutes you can wait for 60s, `sleep 60`

Comment: This did it, thanks. Does it break automatically when it reaches a success? Hopefully one of those repeated commands goes through.

Comment: it works iff the yum command uses return code properly to signal if it failed or not; if it does, then when it's successful the infinite loop will be broken.

Comment: Why not simply `while ! yum install httpd; do sleep 10; done`?

Comment: @MichałPolitowski, what's the difference between yours and the one posted up there?

Comment: @zack There should not be any, except mine is shorter and not as roundabout with simulating an infinite loop using a conditional loop and then simulating a conditional loop by breaking out of an infinite loop.

Comment: there's no simulation of any kind of loop: there's just a loop, from which we get out on a condition. Your solution may work on ksh, but does not in sh and bash. So, it depends on the shell the OP has - sh and bash are very common on "linux"

Comment: bash understands that syntax just fine, and has no complaints with M. Politowski's loop.  The same with the Z and Debian Almquist shells.

Comment: @JdeBP bourne shell doesn't, I thought wrongly it was the same for bash.

Comment: Fedora doesn't have a Bourne shell.

Comment: @JdeBP you mean, by default. But I can suppose the user can use it anyway - my longer solution shouldn't work with all of them, or should I add a "does not work with Xyz shells" disclaimer?

Comment: I mean at all.  Linux distributions **don't have** the Bourne shell.  The (POSIX compatible) shells that come with the questioner's system (and indeed with Linux distributions in general) have no complaints with M. Politowski's loop.  And all of this "but-but-but it depends upon the shell" is nonsense.  It's actually standardized POSIX Shell Command Language syntax that all of the aforementioned shells (apart from the one that Linux **doesn't have at all**, and which pre-dates POSIX in any case) have to support.

Comment: disclaimer:this is not to say Politowski suggestion isn't good. I'm just saying it may not work with some shell:this is true for my solution too,but it turns out it worked on all the shells I had the chance to try; not so for Politowski correct method,e.g it doesn't work on default shell on a solaris sys.Saying no Linux distros have bourne shell is no point,since you can install it,for whatever purpose, on Fedora too. It's just likely you haven't. Anyway, no need for arguing:OP can try whatever works or looks nicer/clearer for him.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm no stranger to programming, so any code is good. I am, however, a noob in Linux, and I'm surprised it can run the code from the CLI.